# Force http for subdomain without SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I recently moved servers and redeveloped the website at the same time. Previously all pages were served via https and I wanted to change this so only cart pages were via https. Also I wanted to clean up the url a bit. Old urls were:

```
https://secure.mydomain.com/onlinestore/index.php
```

and I removed the secure prefix and the subfolder so it is now:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php
```

Problem is I wanted people who clicked on old links or bookmarks to be redirected to the new page. I got this working with htaccess. However the new SSL only covers the root domain and not the secure subdomain. So if someone clicks an old link it brings up "This Connection is Untrusted" before it can redirect. Works fine if i change https to http.

**So what I want to know is if there is anyway I can force http instead of https before it checks the SSL cert.**

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. With conventional SSL, your web server doesn't even get to see the URL before certificate negotiation happens. It just sees a connection on port 443 and starts doing SSL negotiation. The browser then sees the mismatched cert and throws an exception.

However, more modern browsers and web servers (see Wikipedia for the list) support a TLS extension called [Server Name Identification (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which allows the client to send the hostname it's requesting before the server has to respond with a certificate. At that point you'll need to have certificates for both secure.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com on that server, and it'll need to be configured to respond with the proper certificate.

Comment: I was thinking that was going to be the case. Thanks for your reply!