# How to force specific pages in wordpress to be non SSL (http)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Currently I have my ssl forced on a pages where it is needed and it works great. 
Problem is on all other pages user can click in address bar and add "https" causing some pages to load with error about mixed content etc. 
Same happens if someone visits page with https link.
How can I use either worpress functions.php or htaccess file to force specific page URL to always use non-ssl version of website?

Edit:
I just don't see how suggested duplicate is a duplicate. There is no example of any htaccess code and post author seems to mention he managed to create some solution but without code this does not help me.

What I need is what would seem simple redirect like

https://domain.com/page1 -> http://domain.com/page1

Shouldn't something like that be possible with either htaccess or just wordpress functions.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force http for subdomain without SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353294/force-http-for-subdomain-without-ssl)

Comment: Why not fixing mixed content ? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: Problem is users can go https on any page, so there are too many pages to check for mixed content. That is why I need at least temporary fix with redirect.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/someurl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

above seemed to work for me.

Redirects from https to http just for /someurl